# A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported (async and await)

Tags: .net, async-await, httpcontext

I have an application written in .Net 4.8 which is working as a minimal API.
Everything was working perfect unit I moved into .Net 6.

After update, following code start to throw error and add additional content to the response:

```
app.MapPost("/zxc/asd", ([FromBody] ModelDto modelDto,
        IEndpointHelper endpointHelper, HttpContext httpContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    => httpContext.FromResponseMessage(endpointHelper.Process(modelDto, cancellationToken)));
```

Content which was added: "Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported".

I was able to fix this issue by changing my code into asynchronous however this also required some workaround.

```
app.MapPost("/zxc/asd", async ([FromBody] ModelDto modelDto,
        IEndpointHelper endpointHelper, HttpContext httpContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    => await DoAsync(httpContext, modelDto, cancellationToken, endpointHelper));

async Task DoAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ModelDto modelDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEndpointHelper endpointHelper) => 
    await httpContext.FromResponseMessageAsync(endpointHelper.Process(modelDto, cancellationToken));
```

What is strange, I cannot run httpContext.FromResponseMessageAsync straight from app.MapPost as then i am retrieving following error: "A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger ..."

Any idea why this is working in such way ? Or maybe how to remove this additional method ?

Comment: I suspect the `MapPost` overloads are different for those two cases. Checking the call signatures of each one should give a clue.

Answer (score 2):

Credits to https://github.com/Arcade-Dev

Wrapped version with `=> await DoAsync(...)` returns `Task` and will execute whatever is in the wrapper, and for the Task under MapPost, it will return void.

`=> await httpContext.FromResponseMessageAsync(...)` however returns `Task<HttpContext>`, which is why it tries to serialize the entire `HttpContext` as a response, probably attaching it to itself as a response somewhere in the framework, causing a cycle.
So changing from lambda to lambda with brackets will change the return type of the handler thus resolving the issue.

Solution:

```
app.MapPost("/zxc/asd", async ([FromBody] ModelDto modelDto, IEndpointHelper endpointHelper, HttpContext httpContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   => 
   {
       await httpContext.FromResponseMessageAsync(endpointHelper.Process(modelDto, cancellationToken));
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing, you could switch from [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/), [default in .Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0) to [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), here called asynchronously.

```cs
app.MapPost("/zxc/asd", new Delegate((Func<ModelDto, IEndpointHelper, HttpContext, CancellationToken, Task<IActionResult>>)
    (async (modelDto, endpointHelper, httpContext, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        var result = await endpointHelper.Process(modelDto, cancellationToken);
        var jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        return await httpContext.FromResponseMessageAsync(jsonResult);
    })));
```

If the object cycle error persists, an alternative would be to manually handle the serialization and deserialization to avoid cycles. For example, again for testing:

```cs
app.MapPost("/zxc/asd", new Delegate((Func<ModelDto, IEndpointHelper, HttpContext, CancellationToken, Task<IActionResult>>)
    (async (modelDto, endpointHelper, httpContext, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        var result = await endpointHelper.Process(modelDto, cancellationToken);
        var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings 
        { 
            ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore 
        };
        var jsonResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, settings);
        return await httpContext.FromResponseMessageAsync(jsonResult);
    })));
```